# Binding/listening to events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I made a jQuery plugin that calls its functions at timed events. I want to provide those who use the plugin the ability to listen to these functions when they are called and add code to be performed when the functions are triggered.

This may be a simple question but I can’t wrap my head around it. What is the best method to achieve this? I can only find information on binding handlers to events, not events to events. I want something like the code below:

```
  $( "body" ).bind( "pluginInstance.functionName", function() {
    console.log( "triggered" );
  });
```

Comment: Maybe this? http://css-tricks.com/custom-events-are-pretty-cool/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could invoke the declared function you passed to the plugin. Example:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function(callback){
   callback();
}


$('elem').myPlugin(function(){

    console.log("triggered");

})
```

If you wanted to be more sophisticated about it you could set the callback function to an object and refer to the object versus the arguments, which is more specific and easier to read:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function(options){
   options.callback();
}


$('elem').myPlugin(
   var options = {
      callback: function(){
         console.log('triggered')
      }
   }
)
```

Comment: Yes that makes sense, this seems to be similar logic to the comment above too, which also makes sense. I'm going to try it now. Thanks.

Comment: It worked. This and the link in the comment helped a lot thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would allow the plugin consumer to pass in an [options](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#accepting-options) hash to your plugin's constructor with optional event methods / properties that you have predetermined.  I would also have a 'defaults' object defined in your plugin that defines those available properties and events that the user can override.  You can use the jQuery [extend](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) method to copy any defaults that the user did not pass in within the constructor.

As an example, you may have a 'onSlide' event that the user can add a callback for in your plugin.  I would set the plugin up as follows:

```
$.fn.newPlugin = function(options){
   var defaults = {
        onSlide: null,
        onRightClick: null
   };
   var settings = $.extend(defaults, options);
   //Pretend something in your plugin happens and you want to optionally 
   //invoke the user's passed in onSlide method if they set it
   if(settings.onSlide != null){
       settings.onSlide();
   }
}
```

When the user is consuming your plugin they can pass the 'onSlide' handler into the constructor:

```
$('elem').newPlugin({
    onSlide: function(){
        alert('slide event triggered');
    }
});
```

Comment: That is a callback, not an event, you could only register a single handler

Comment: @JuanMendes take a look at the documentation here https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#accepting-options  You can pass an options hash

Comment: Not if two different pieces of the code need to listen to the same event. Usually you can just call `$jQueryEl.on('custom.event')` multiple times and they will all be notified

Comment: @JuanMendes you are definitely correct about that, I guess you would then have to trigger the global event in your passed in handler.  I was more following the pattern that they use in the jQuery UI Widget Factory where they let you pass in functions for events.  You make a good point thought.  I will up-vote your comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom events http://css-tricks.com/custom-events-are-pretty-cool/. See http://jsfiddle.net/3L45H/1 and https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

From your plugin, you can call the following to trigger an event

```
$(this.element).trigger('pluginInstance.functionName');
```

And listen for it as you do any other DOM events

```
$('body').bind( "pluginInstance.functionName", function() {
    console.log( "triggered" );
});

$('body').myPlugin();
```